# How do I replace all variable text in a column between quotes that ends with .pdf with static data?

Tags: notepad++

I'm trying to edit all rows of a .TXT file that contain any text between quotes ending in .pdf with static text that ends in .pdf.

Example.

I want to change something like this:

```
Data,Data,Data,"VariableName_1.pdf",data,data
Data,Data,Data,"VariableName_2.pdf",data,data
Data,Data,Data,"VariableName_3.pdf",data,data
Data,Data,Data,"VariableName_4.pdf",data,data
Data,Data,Data,"VariableName_5.pdf",data,data
```

To this something like this:

```
Data,Data,Data,"StaticName.pdf",data,data
Data,Data,Data,"StaticName.pdf",data,data
Data,Data,Data,"StaticName.pdf",data,data
Data,Data,Data,"StaticName.pdf",data,data
Data,Data,Data,"StaticName.pdf",data,data
```

Can this be done?

Comment: The data is unclear : Are all "VariableName" and "StaticName" always the same?

Comment: The variable name is always unique. The static name will always be the same

Answer (score 1):

Try the following to find texts between qutoes and ending with `pdf`:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+"\K.+(?=\.pdf")`
- Replace with: `StaticName`
- Search mode: `Regular expression`
- Press <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your description looks too simple. In any case, it can be
done this way, if this is what you meant:

Ctrl+H to enter the Replace dialog
Find what: `VariableName_\d`
Replace with: `StaticName`
Search mode: `Regular expression`
Click: `Replace All`.